# How to determine textsize of toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I defined a text for the toolbar in the manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name=".instandhalter_screen.WikiInstandhalterScreenActivity"
            android:label="Instandhalter  >  Wiki"
            android:parentActivityName=".instandhalter_screen.InstandhalterScreenActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.derdoenerdon.ressourcencockpit2.instandhalter_screen.InstandhalterScreenActivity" />
        </activity>
```

I would like to "determine" the size of the text `"Instandhalter  >  Wiki"`

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a theme and add it in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/customizedTheme"
```

To create the theme, in the file res/styles.xml:

```
<style name="customizedTheme" >
    <item name="android:textSize">50dp</item>
    <-- You can add more style elements here -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, 

but is there a way to determine my "default" value?

Comment: Yes, just change the 50dp for whatever value you want

Comment: It does not work. 
It will change the textSize of the text, when I need some one for example Text in Button or whatever, but the size of the Text in actionbar is still same..

Answer (score 0):

You can change ActionBar Title's text size by simply adding android:textSize attribute to the  that you have defined in the styles.xml file.

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- set the size of action bar title . -->
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, 

how can I add a specific text style to it?

Comment: You can use HTML for this with the action bar in the activity like this   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='"+Your color in hex here+"'>" + Your title here + "</font>"));